# What's the negation of "E is uncountable" ??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think "E is countable or finite."
But when I asked my professor, he said "E is countable."

Comment: For a lot of people, "countable" means "countably infinite or finite" or "at most countably infinite". This makes sense since you can obviously count finite sets too.

Comment: Anyway, "countable or finite" is correct no matter whether one interprets "countable" as "having the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$", or as "having the cardinality of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$". At worst, "or finite" is redundant.

Comment: It's just a terminology question; for somebody, “countable” means “having the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$”; for someone else it means “having the same cardinality as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$”. So your question can't be answered: your teacher uses the second convention, which is not universally accepted.

Comment: @egreg But with that interpretation finite sets would literally be uncountable

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm not saying I like the terminology.

Comment: @egreg I didn't want to imply that. Besides, opposites of everyday language need not transfer to mathematical definitions, cf. *open* vs. *closed* in topology., i.e. "we" are free to make a definition of *uncountable* that is not the same as not *countable*. I've also seen people not regarding the empty set as finite, so for them "not uncountable" might in fact expand to "countable or finite or empty" - yuck. I myself sometimes jokingly speak about "uncountably finite" for big numbers (i.e. bigger than I could literally count)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In mathematical terminology one should not confuse “uncountable” with “not countable”: the first is a *single* term that might not mean the same as “the negation of countable”. Unfortunate terminology plagues math: think to “point of discontinuity”, which a continuous function can actually have.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: $4$?

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that finite is countable.